# initializer lists with objects is non-portable?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading [Mozilla's C++ portability guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/C++_Portability_Guide) where one of the advice states that:

> **Don't use initializer lists with objects**
>
> Non-portable example (at least, this used to be nonportable, because HP-UX!):
>
> `SubtlePoint myPoint = {300, 400};`
>
> This is more of a style thing at this point, but why not splurge and get yourself a nice constructor?

and I'm rather curious about this line "*Non-portable example (at least, this used to be nonportable, because HP-UX!)*". How come initializer lists are/were non-portable and in what sense? Are they safe to use now? And what does the term *HP-UX* refers to?

Comment: Probably some horribly outdated system with an even more obsolete C++ compiler.

Comment: HP-UX normally refers to a certain operating system named HP-UX. Have you tried to google it? I'm not sure what 8HP-UX is (probably a typo).

Comment: As read, I think I must disagree with their definition of "Non-portable" as 'Some platform is not up to date, and we must pander to it'. At least I usually take "non-portable" to mean _not defined by the Standard, but might work on some implementations, if you're lucky_. The syntax quoted **is** defined (if redundant), so Mozilla chose ambiguous wording at best

Comment: HP-UX is an operating system. If I recall correctly, its compiler used to have a reputation for not paying much attention to standardisation.

Comment: @underscore_d: I think their definition of "Non-portable" is correct.  Either you pander to a particular system's non-conforming compiler, or you don't support that platform.  Now, the amount of pain that is involved in supporting a platform is one factor that feeds into the decision, but once you have made the decision you stick with it.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yeah, it's not INcorrect, just needlessly confusing, as this question proves! The definition I gave can be unambiguously described as _implementation-defined_. Within a C++ coding guide, that's far preferable. However, this same guide doesn't seem to explain what it means by non-portable, why it was, or why it possibly isn't anymore... so precise wording would seem to be asking a bit much ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How come initializer lists are/were non-portable and in what sense?

The guide that you quote implies that they aren't/weren't portable in the sense that they would not work in HP-UX. Since using initializer list with objects is well defined by the standard, this implies that the compiler used in HP-UX does not conform to it. The guide does not specify, *how* it breaks in HP-UX.

> And what does the term HP-UX refers to?

It is an [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX).

> Are they safe to use now?

If you don't need to support HP-UX, or other system that does not conform to the standard, then it is and has been perfectly safe.

"*at least, this **used to be** nonportable*" might be due to Mozilla no longer officially supporting new versions of their products on HP-UX, or that a new version of the compiler on HP-UX is now conformant. This is just my speculation.